# Is there a DevOps API that lets you find all files with a certain name?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to query a DevOps Git repository to find all files named `METADATA.yml`, regardless of what folder they live in.  It's pretty easy to find that file if you know the exact folder, such as the root folder:

```
/_apis/git/repositories/79a24c6c-ca83-41c7-b298-202792bf59df/items?scopePath=/METADATA.yml
```

There also appears to be a `recursionLevel` parameter, but it's only used if you're requesting a tree (an entire folder hierarchy).  The [Get Items Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get-items-batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) API also seems interesting, but it just lets you get a whole bunch of individual files at once, but you'd need to know the exact path of each one.

There's some APIs around [Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/search/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) as well, but this seems to only let you search for contents within the file.

I could recursively walk each folder looking for all files, but this would be slow and take many API calls.  The program I'm writing needs to find these files across dozens of repositories and be somewhat fast.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer this REST API:[Code Search](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Frest%2Fapi%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsearch%2Fcode-search-results%2Ffetch-code-search-results%3Fview%3Dazure-devops-rest-6.0%26tabs%3DHTTP&data=05%7C01%7Cv-douxu%40microsoft.com%7Cc083ce52098b44917e2408dac16daf4f%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C638034974110329773%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=BiuNX6JMQD7lEHKGpYrWCr9Ynqp60qzI6t7lyDd75W8%3D&reserved=0)

For example:

URL:

```
POST https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Request Body

```
        {
  "searchText": "the search text",
  "$skip": 0,
  "$top": 1,
  "filters": {
    "Project": [
      "MyFirstProject"
    ],
    "Repository": [
      "MyFirstProject"
    ],
    "Path": [
      "/"
    ],
    "Branch": [
      "master"
    ],
  },
  "$orderBy": [
    {
      "field": "filename",
      "sortOrder": "ASC"
    }
  ],
  "includeFacets": true
}
```

Request demo in postman:
[image: test in postman]

From the response body , the count is 4 and you can find 4 files with the certain name “azure-pipelines” in your project. By the way, you can add other filters e.g. branch, repository according your needs.

**Update:**

1 Refr to [Function Code Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/search/advanced-search#codefunctions) for a list of supported code type filters

2 See the name "matches" of  CodeResult in  above example, Key identifies the area in which hits were found, for ex: file content/file name etc. If you just want to find files with file name, you can manually add filter in your code to handle the results and filter the files matching the key "fileName".

match filename [image: match filename]
match content [image: math content]

Comment: Is there documentation on what the "filters" object in the Request Body?  The doc you linked to simply says "object".  Your above example doesn't work because it would find any file with the word "azure-pipelines" in it.

Comment: I have updated my answer and you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/functional-code-search?view=azure-devops#codefunctions  for a list of supported code type filters.